# Xcode 6 displays Xcode 7 Beta error messages after installing the beta

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6, xcode7-beta2

I have a project which I developed under Xcode 6. Since only Xcode 7 lets me install apps on a physcial device without developer programm, I opened the same project that ran without errors in Xcode 6 in Xcode 7 and got 35 issues. I didn't want to resolve them so I closed the Beta version. Even though nothing was changed in the source code, I still got 24 issues when I opened the same project that before ran smoothly in Xcode 6 when reopening in Xcode 6, stuff like "println has been changed to print", even though it's still Xcode 6. Does anybody know how to fix this issue? Even the SplitViewController template produces a whole lot of errors!

Comment: I assume that you already tried "Clean", "Clean Build Folder" etc ?

Comment: I didn't. I am almost a complete beginner with Swift Programming and Xcode.

Comment: Press Alt+Shift+Cmd+K to clean build folder. Then recompile.

Comment: While I will try to resolve this issue, I would still be curious as to why there are so many error messages. Errors like println/print are selx explanatory, but why is there an issue with the MasterDetailTemplate from Apple? Even that didnt work anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer was posted in the comments to my question by the user Avt:

Press Alt+Shift+Cmd+K to clean build folder. Then recompile. –  Avt

Answer (score 0):

Xcode remembers the warnings of the last compile process in the project. So the warnings will automatically disappear as soon as you compile the app again using Xcode 6.